# @Autowire an Interface as Map<String, InterfaceName> is possible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

Let's say I have a "SomeInterface" and I have two springComponentImpl that implements that "SomeInterface".

I know I can autowire both implementations, together at once, with:

```
@Autowire
private List<SomeInterface> springComponentsImplList;
```

Could I inject them in a way like this?:

```
@Autowire
private Map<String,SomeInterface> springComponentsImplList;
```

So that way I could get the implementation by a "key"? It would be perfect if that key is the class name or something and generated automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work out-of-the-box, where the map contains the bean names as keys and the corresponding bean instances as values:

```java
@Autowired
private Map<String, Foo> allBeansOfType;
```

But you may also try to get all bean instances of a particular type along with their names using [`ListableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html):

```java
private Map<String, Foo> allBeansOfType;

@Autowired
public MyClass(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.allBeansOfType = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(Foo.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the spring beans into two separate `List`

**First approach :** If you have only each of them, then name them differently and use `@Qualifier`

**Service Interface**

```
public interface ServiceInterf {

}
```

**ImplementOne**

```
@Service("implementOne")
public class ImplementOne implements ServiceInterf {

}
```

**ImplementTwo**

```
@Service("implementTwo")
public class ImplementTwo implements ServiceInterf {

}
```

And you can use `@Qualifier`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("implementOne")
private List<ServiceInterf> implementOne;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("implementTwo")
private List<ServiceInterf> implementTwo;
```

**Second approach :** If you have multiple of them, then you can declare them in config class using `@Qualifier` [5.2. Using @Qualifier to Select Beans](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections)

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("implementOne")
public ServiceInterf getServiceInterf1() {
    return new ImplementOne();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("implementOne")
public ServiceInterf getServiceInterf2() {
    return new ImplementOne();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("implementTwo")
public ServiceInterf getServiceInterf3() {
    return new ImplementTwo();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("implementTwo")
public ServiceInterf getServiceInterf4() {
    return new ImplementTwo();
}
```

And also if you want to do them into `Map` use constructor injection

```
private Map<String, List<ServiceInterf>> mapOfLists;

@Autowired
public TestMap(@Qualifier("implementOne") List<ServiceInterf> implementOne, 
               @Qualifier("implementTwo") List<ServiceInterf> implementTwo) {
    mapOfLists = Map.of("implementOne",implementOne,"implementTwo",implementTwo);  
    // Map.of is from java 9 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the discussion-

So, what you are asking is possible, you can do it like this -

Create a service interface -

```
public interface SayHelloService {
    String sayHello();
}
```

Create multiple implementations of this interface -

```
@Service("ENG")
public class SayHelloInEnglish implements SayHelloService {
    String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

another implementation -

```
@Service("SPN")
public class SayHelloInSpanish implements SayHelloService {
    String sayHello() {
        return "hola";
    }
}
```

When you autowire your service, you can autowire it like this -

```
  private Map<String, SayHelloService> sayHelloService;

  @Autowired
  public HelloController(Map<String, SayHelloService> sayHelloService) {
    this.sayHelloService = sayHelloService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/hello/{lang}")
  public String sayHello(@PathVariable String lang) {
    String msg = this.sayHelloService.get(lang).sayHello();
    return msg;
  }
```

Now based on your param, the corresponding implementation class will be picked up.
Hope it helps.
Mark as answer if it did :p